# Does context_switch in different CPU cores performed simultaneously in CFS linux?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, cpu

I am exploring implementation of context_switch in CFS.

To understand the context_switch concept in depth, I looked into context_switch method implementation of kernel/sched/core.c file.

```
context_switch(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *prev,
           struct task_struct *next)
```

So, context_switch() function is called whenever there is a need of context_switch between two processes.

I have Intel Core i7 system having 8 cores, running both Debian 8 and Ubuntu-16.04, kernel 3.16.x and 3.18.x.

I have following questions -

1. If (process-1 and process-2) of Core-1 and (process-3 and process-4)
   of Core-5 want to context_switch at the same time, will the
   context_switch performed at the same time in different cores ?

   2. If yes, 
      (a) Does individual call of context_switch maintains stack/memory in their local cache ?

      (b) Does context_switch on one core has any impact on context_switch on other cores ?

Comment: I don't know how exactly the CFS is implemented but a reasonable approach to scheduling is having a global queue of processes and each core that fetches the next process (according to affinity). So each core switches its own context independently but for sync. An implementation has room for optimisations of course.